# How to click the mouse within a vb.net app programatically (without taking mouse focus from user)

Tags: vb.net, mouse

I'm trying to automate a task that's time consuming and simple. However it requires a mouse click inside a 3rd party program. I've got the 3rd party program inside a panel in my vb.net app and I'm now working on how to click inside that panel. I can do it reasonably easily but this requires the app to have focus and the mouse pointer to move to the specified location - not ideal as I want this running in the background! Is there a way around this?

Comment: You cannot interact with a 3rd party program without having focus unless the 3rd party app provides an API or a way to access the controls within the app directly.  But, it might help if you let us know what app :)